# How to add Jfrog Artifactory as a docker registry in Spinnaker?

Tags: docker, artifactory, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I am trying to add JFrog Artifactory as a Docker registry account in my Spinnaker installation. I do the following:

```
hal config provider docker-registry enable

ADDRESS=server.company.com.jfrog.io
REPOSITORIES=abc/contrepo
USERNAME=abc@xyz.com

hal config provider docker-registry account add jfrog-stage \
    --address $ADDRESS \
    --repositories $REPOSITORIES \
    --username $USERNAME \
    --password
```

However, I get the following error:

```
  Failure
Problems in
  default.provider.dockerRegistry.jfrog-stage:
! ERROR Unable to reach repository: Hostname
  server.company.com.jfrog.io not verified:
    certificate: sha1/iIkgakshaaukdhdhidhiudsihsdih=
    DN: CN=*.jfrog.io
    subjectAltNames: [*.jfrog.io, jfrog.io].
```

Does anyone have any experience setting up JFrog registry on Spinnaker? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: it might be helpful if we can see the config vile in ~/.hal/config or wherever you have it stored on the environment where you run your hal commands

Answer (score 0):

I got same error when i try to add a private artifact address.
Solved it by insert the CA certificate of artifact into JDK keystore.
Here is the command.

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias ebaotech -file /tmp/git.cer -storepass changeit -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

"/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts" is keystore file of my environment.

"/tmp/git.cer" is certificate of my artifact address.

Restart halyard after that.

One more note, if the "clouddriver" is running in different server, you also have to update keystore of that server.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this!!
It worked for me.

```
     bash-5.0$ hal config provider docker-registry enable
    + Get current deployment
      Success
    + Edit the dockerRegistry provider
      Success
    Validation in default.provider.dockerRegistry:
    - WARNING Provider dockerRegistry is enabled, but no accounts have
      been configured.
    
    + Successfully enabled dockerRegistry
    bash-5.0$ hal config provider docker-registry account add artifactory \
     --address  https://docker-dev-artifactory.*****.com \
     --insecure-registry true \
     --username niraj.gurung --password
    
    Your docker registry password: 
    + Get current deployment
      Success
    + Add the artifactory account
      Success
    Validation in default.provider.dockerRegistry.artifactory:
    - WARNING Your docker registry has no repositories specified, and
      the registry's catalog is empty. Spinnaker will not be able to deploy any images
      until some are pushed to this registry.
    ? Manually specify some repositories for this docker registry to
      index.
    
    + Successfully added account artifactory for provider
      dockerRegistry.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this answer may help, please, add an explanation in order to make it more understandable for the StackOverflow community